# Class string setter using reference

Tags: c++

If a class has a string property, and the setter for that property takes a `const std::string&`, is there a risk of the string going out of scope?

```
class Foo {
   public:
      std::string name;
      void SetName(const std::string &name){
          this->name = name;
      }
};
```

So what happens here

```
{
     //...
     std::string name = "name";
     foo.SetName(name);
} // name goes out of scope
```

This seems to work fine but it doesn't make sense to me. If I passed a reference to anything else, or a pointer, I would have big problems. Is there something special about `std::string`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a risk of the string going out of scope?

No, because the assignment makes a copy of the data.

> This seems to work fine but it doesn't make sense to me. If I passed a reference to anything else, or a pointer, I would have big problems. Is there something special about std::string?

No, this would be the case for absolutely any kind of object. The key is that you are copying the referred-to thing inside the member function, while the reference is still valid. Doesn't matter what happens to it after that.

---

A more modern way to do this would be:

```
class Foo {
   public:
      std::string name;
      void SetName(std::string name){
          this->name = std::move(name);
      }
};
```

Now, the function body does a *move* rather than a copy; the copying is now done in the by-value function argument instead, unless the calling scope used `std::move`! This way, you do not force the calling scope's data to be copied if it does not need to be.

Comment: Oops, yah, this make more sense. But I would have a problem if `Foo`'s `name` property was a reference.

Comment: @terratermatwoa That's right; you can only initialise a reference so the problem would only exist in your `Foo` constructor, but that constructor would be making a dangling reference. Anything you did with it after that (including assigning through it) would be illegal.